# Toolbar with a wrong height and shadow

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I am trying to add shadow to a toolbar using elevation and the Design Library. The layout code is something like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ... >
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout ... >
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout ... >
       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/app_bar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
           app:contentInsetStart="16dp"
           android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
           android:elevation="16dp"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The complete application source code it is available on [github](https://github.com/robertoallende/UISkel/blob/wrong_tool_bar/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_item_list.xml#L32-L39).

The problem is that the toolbar height or the shadow are not behaving as I expect. If you watch the screen capture below, you can notice the problem.

What I need to do is to display the shadow below of the blue area.

[image: Current Toolbar]

Any hint is very appreciated.

Comment: The drop shadow may be coming from your elevation. Beyond that, I have never used `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, nor `AppBarLayout`, and so I do not even really know what you mean about your height not working as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34141797/3225458), it's by implementation of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` - elevation is removed if `CollapsingToolbarLayout` shows non-pinned elements:

```
if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) == scrollRange) {
  // If we have some pinned children, and we're offset to only show those views,
  // we want to be elevate
  ViewCompat.setElevation(layout, layout.getTargetElevation());
} else {
  // Otherwise, we're inline with the content
  ViewCompat.setElevation(layout, 0f);
}
```

So, all I can suggest is to make your own `CollapsingToolbarLayout` by copying original `CollapsingToolbarLayout` from Google, and make changes in this condition.

Answer (score 4):

Move the elevation to the AppBarLayout. CollapsingToolbarLayout changes in size, so setting it on the AppBarLayout creates the shadow at the right position.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout ... >
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:elevation="16dp">
  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout ... >
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ... />
  </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. I already tried that, so adding the background color to the AppBarLayout and it doesn't work.